# Relation of equipotence is an equivalence relation?

Tags: real-analysis

How do I argue that equipotence relation is an equivalnce relation over power set of $X$?

I have started self-study of real analysis with Royden's book. I don't see what does equipotence relation on a single set X mean? Because equipotence is defined to be the property of two sets A and B, if there is a one-to-one and onto mapping between A and B. Then what does equipotence relation on power set of $X, \mathcal{P}(X)$, would mean? The $\mathcal{P}(X)$ conatains many subsets, does equipotence on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ mean that there is an invertible mapping between any two sets in $\mathcal{P}(X)$, whenever possible?

Comment: The same way you argue that any other equivalence relation is indeed an equivalence relation: show that is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

Comment: Right now, this is not a good question, as it is lacking **context.**  To improve it, you might state the relevant definitions and give some idea of what you have tried.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I have edited the question now. Thanks!

Comment: `I don't see what does equipotence relation on a single set X mean?` But the question is about equipotence being an equivalence relation over the `power set of X`, ***not*** `X`.

Comment: @dxiv can you please explain what is it over power set of X.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Do you know/remember what the [power set of a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) is? If not, then you have some ground to cover before moving forward on this problem..

Comment: @dxiv I know, it is a collection of all possible subsets of X.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Then what you wrote `I don't see what does equipotence relation on a single set X mean?` doesn't apply, and all you need to do is apply the definitions of an equivalence relation, as noted in the very first comment. If you have difficulties while doing that, please edit the question and specify *what* and *where* exactly that is. The more specific you are, the better the chances of a helpful answer.

Comment: @dxiv I think I have found out a specific problem in my understanding. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

(*Too long for a comment*.)

> I don't see what does equipotence relation on a single set X mean?

The question is about equipotence being "*an equivalence relation* ***over power set*** *of $X$*". Nowhere is it mentioned or implied that equipotence would be defined "*on* ***a single set*** *X*".

> Because equipotence is defined to be the property of two sets A and B, if there is a one-to-one and onto mapping between A and B.

In other words, a bijection between $A$ and $B$. That's correct.

> Then what does equipotence relation on power set of $X, \mathcal{P}(X)$, would mean?

Precisely what the previous definition says:  for any two sets $\,A, B \in \mathcal{P}(X)\,$ (which is the same as $\,A, B \subseteq X\,$ by the definition of the power set), $A$ and $B$ are said to be equipotent iff there exists a bijection between $A$ and $B$.

> The $\mathcal{P}(X)$ conatains many subsets, does equipotence on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ mean that there is an invertible mapping between any two sets in $\mathcal{P}(X)$, whenever possible?

That's worded rather confusingly. Of course ***not*** any two subsets of $\,X\,$ are equipotent. But two subsets $A,B$ are indeed equipotent iff there exists a bijection between them.

Comment: Thanks @dxiv. It clears all my doubts.